# Accessing my local baseX DB from another machine

Tags: web-services, rest, networking, localhost, basex

I use BaseX on my machine to simplify how I interact with some XML data and I run it using the BaseX http service and access it via Rest and a localhost address.

I don't really have any network experience, and I want to know how I would go about accessing this data from anther machine. Would it be possible using the current configuration, or do I need to do something to rout the external requests.

Hope this question is clear. Like I said I have little-no experience dealing with these sorts of networking issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseX (or to be more specific, the embedded web server `basexhttp`) per default listens on port 8984, available to all other computers that can access you machine. Given no firewall (or NAT) prevents access, you should already be able to reach your machine under `http://[ip-address]:8984`. More in-depth reference is available in the BaseX Wiki: [general information](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Web_Application), [configuration options](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#HTTP_Options) and [startup options](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Command-Line_Options#HTTP_Server).

WIth other words: if you didn't change any configuration, you will already be able to access the service.

If you want to offer web services using BaseX, consider adding a reverse proxy like nginx. This has several advantages:

- configurable caching
- serving static resources directly, without going through BaseX
- reducing exposition of BaseX to the internet (nginx and similar products have a much broader user base, thus are analyzed for security issues in more depth)
- providing TLS-encryption
- providing web applications from different application servers, like a website powered by BaseX, and others using PHP
- possibly quite a bunch I didn't consider right now

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the info.